# How to use Association Aliases on mysql db using sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, many-to-many, aliases

I have a MERN project working with MySQL DB.
The project has models with these relationships.

```js
db.course.belongsToMany(db.user, {
  through: db.userCourse
});
db.user.belongsToMany(db.course, {
  through: db.userCourse
});
db.user.hasMany(db.userCourse);
db.userCourse.belongsTo(db.user);
db.course.hasMany(db.userCourse);
db.userCourse.belongsTo(db.course);
```

I create my associations like this and it works fine.

```js
 user.addCourse(course, { through: { expirationDate: new Date() }});
                console.log(`>>added Course id=${course.id} to User id=${user.id}`);
                res.status(200).json({message : {msgBody : "You have successfully registered for this course!", msgError: false}});
                return user;
```

However, I decided to add aliases to my associations like this

```js
db.course.belongsToMany(db.user, {
  as: 'subscriptions',
  through: db.userCourse
});
db.user.belongsToMany(db.course, {
  as: 'subscribers',
  through: db.userCourse
});
db.user.hasMany(db.userCourse);
db.userCourse.belongsTo(db.user);
db.course.hasMany(db.userCourse);
db.userCourse.belongsTo(db.course);
```

After I did that, my addCourse function no longer works. I get the error message, addCourse is not a function. Please any pointer on what I am doing wrong here will help. Here is the full code adding the relationships

```js
exports.addCourse = (req, res, next) => {
 const {userId, courseId} = req.body;
    return User.findByPk(userId)
      .then((user) =>{
          if(!user) {
              console.log('User not found!');
              res.status(401).json({message : {msgBody : "User not found!", msgError: true}});
              return null;
          }
          
          return Course.findByPk(courseId)
            .then((course) =>{
                if(!course) {
                    console.log('Course not found!');
                    res.status(401).json({message : {msgBody : "Course not found!", msgError: true}});
                    return null;
                }

               
                user.addCourse(course, { through: { expirationDate: new Date() }});
                console.log(`>>added Course id=${course.id} to User id=${user.id}`);
                res.status(200).json({message : {msgBody : "You have successfully registered for this course!", msgError: false}});
                return user;

            });
      })
      .catch((error) =>{
          console.log('>> Error while adding Course to User:', error);
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since aliases were created. The function

```js
 user.addCourse(course, { through: { expirationDate: new Date() }});
                console.log(`>>added Course id=${course.id} to User id=${user.id}`);
                res.status(200).json({message : {msgBody : "You have successfully registered for this course!", msgError: false}});
                return user;
```

Should now be called using the corresponding alias like this

```js
 user.addSubscriber(course, { through: { expirationDate: new Date() }});
                console.log(`>>added Course id=${course.id} to User id=${user.id}`);
                res.status(200).json({message : {msgBody : "You have successfully registered for this course!", msgError: false}});
                return user;
```